# Disable Content Delivery search in 9.5

Tags: content-delivery, search, sites-9.5

Does anyone know the definitive steps to disabling Content Delivery search in 9.5?

[SDL Docs](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/816426/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/disabling-the-content-delivery-search-feature) says set **springprofilesactive** (if an environment var) to "*default*" but [this support article says](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000014087) use the value "*broker*" for the same environment var.

Is one for Deployer and the other for the Content/Session service?

If you have a single server running several microservices can/should the value be "*default,broker*"?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK - You can disable this in **application.properties**

```
# Active Spring profiles:
# default - enable default functionality
# search - enable search functionality
spring.profiles.active=${springprofilesactive:default,search}
```

This parameter can also be passed in the start-up parameters if you want to control dynamically. Alternatively, you can also update the add-on packages to remove the search indexing pipeline steps and deploy them.

I hope it helps.

Comment: It can be set via an environment variable as well, doesn't have to be application.properties.

Comment: Yes. it's possible but if you are running staging and live in the same instance then how you can control this

Comment: Exactly my last question above!

Comment: I take your point about staging/live - my assumption is env vars aren't suitable in that scenario. But if you need to manage this differently for staging/live, my last question is more can the env var hold the two different values or not.

Comment: ah. okay not sure need to validate